# Openlayers 4 Geolocation is not working

Tags: openlayers, gps, geolocation

```
    geolocation: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.geo = new ol.Geolocation({
        trackingOptions: {
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        },
        projection: self.Map.olMap.getView().getProjection()
    });
},
```

I have this code but if i want to get current position, i get "undefined" message.Why?

```
geo.getPosition() //return undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.geo = new ol.Geolocation({
        tracking: true,
        projection: self.Map.olMap.getView().getProjection()
    });
```

It worked like this, but if you use like this, please wait a while when geolocation getting your lat,lon values. Its late a bit.